# Cannot uninstall Umbraco package that I created, without deleting parent doc types first

Tags: umbraco

I'm hoping someone can shed some light as to why this is happening. I've just started creating my own packages in Umbraco and am having issues with something that should be quite straight forward.

I've created a fairly simple package consisting of a Content page and child pages, doc types, templates, some css and some scripts. I install the package on another Umbraco site and all seems fine. The problem is when I come to uninstall the package, it is trying to remove its parents Document Types, which it cannot do, and it's shouldn't do as these were not in the original package I created.

What am I missing here people?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The package manager will attempt to package up all required dependencies.

When you created your package did you select doctypes that were nested under the parent doctype? If so this is probably why as the parent doctype then becomes a dependency and most likely was actually included in your package. It should be pretty easy to see from the uninstallation page what it is trying to remove and if that doctype is listed it was in your package.

Comment: Thanks for the info! This is exactly what's happening, well kinda... I'm not packaging the parent doc type, but when it comes to uninstalling the package the parent doc types are included. This is really annoying! Do you know of any way around this, maybe writing some kind of uninstall action?

Comment: It's by design. In order to package a child document type by rights you need the parent as the child is dependent on it's existence in the target install. The uninstall action simply attempts to uninstall all that was included in the original package.